# idea（2023.2.5） remote development connect CentOS7.9 git commit Chinese show exception

Tags: intellij-idea

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mm9x7.png)

Idea remotely connects to CentOS7.9 for remote development, and the display of other windows is normal. Currently, it is found that only the Chinese input in the git submission box is too narrow, and the Chinese displayed in the git submission history is also too narrow.